# How to create a SQL view from an SSRS report

Tags: sql, reporting-services, view

Is it possible to create a SQL view using a SSRS report data?
Any thoughts could help.

Thank you

Comment: No, but you could probably create the view using the same query the SSRS report uses.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I am dealing with a very long query (10 pages long) and is getting the data from multiple databases, can a view be generated from different db.?

Comment: Yes.   If you can use the multiple databases in a query, you can use the query in a view.

Comment: @PisoiFlo - In your report, do you have 1 query in a dataset targeting multiple databases or multiple datasets targeting different databases?

Comment: I have 1 query targeting multiple databases

Comment: @  Sébastien Sevrin - I don`t see why it would be an issue in case there are multiple datasets, could you please let me know your thoughts on this?

Comment: @PisoiFlo - It could be a problem if you have several datasets and a lot of custom display rules in the report (grouping, vlookups, ...). And if the report server has access to `DB Server A` and `DB Server B`, but `DB Server A` has no access to `DB Server B`, it could also be an issue. As you have only 1 query, I don't see any reason why you couldn't just take the query from the report and create a view.

Comment: Thank you @ Sébastien Sevrin!